# Fusion Chart - How to change default legend icon version 3.3.1

Tags: fusioncharts

I am using Fusion Chart **version 3.3.1** and I found all the solution as per the requirement on the forum and stackoverflow. Chart is working fine for me but please let me know whether it is possible to change the default icon for legend. We don't want to show that default icon for legend and client has given us the icon for the legend which we need to use it in our fusion chart. Code is given below  ,please let me know if anything i can change here or there is any other configuration for changing the legend icon.

```
<html>
  <head>        
    <title>My First chart using FusionCharts - Using JavaScript</title>         
    <script type="text/javascript" src="FusionCharts.js"></script>
  </head>   
  <body>     
    <div id="chartContainer">FusionCharts XT will load here!</div>   
     <div id="chartContainer1" style="margin-left: 50%;
margin-right: 10%;
margin-top: -22%;">FusionCharts XT will load here!</div>   
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--

      var myChart = new FusionCharts( "Column2D.swf", 
                    "myChartId", "500", "300",  "0", "0");
var dataString ='<chart palette="2" caption="Industries" xAxisName="Days in Month" yAxisName="" labelDisplay="Rotate" showValues="0" decimals="0" formatNumberScale="0" bgcolor="FFFFFF" useRoundEdges="1" bgColor="FFFFFF,FFFFFF" showBorder="0">\n\
 <set value="20" label="Electric Power Generation" color="005C8E"/>\n\
 <set value="32" label="Industrial Processes" color="00759B"/>\n\
 <set value="12" label="Residential and Commercial Activities" color="0296D2"/>\n\
 <set value="20" label="Agriculture" color="40C7F9"/>\n\
 <set value="2" label="Waste Disposal" color="00496C"/>\n\
 </chart>';
  myChart.setXMLData( dataString );
 myChart.render("chartContainer"); 

    // -->  
    </script>      
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: No, it is not possible to show a custom icon instead of default legend of FusionChars, as of now. You may choose to show the desired icons in a table below FusionCharts, as a separate DOM component.

Comment: But if we show our own icon in table format with separate DOM then how will the same functionality works for chart. Like click on legend icon it goes to particular donut element or whatever\.

Comment: @vishal_g It can be achieved by implementing custom JS function which will render a chart with pie sliced out and Re clicking the icon, result in pie to be sliced in.